# Excel VlookUp tips finding a value within a range and returning the value of column next to it

Tags: excel

I have an excel spreadsheet, within that spread sheet I have a ZIP column then I have a ZIPCodes Column Finally I have a county Column.

I am trying to write a formula that states if Zip value is within ZipCodes place the countyName that is in the same row. If is NOT within this row of ZipCodes look into the next one, if the Zip value is within that cell then place the CountyName of THAT row and so on.

I tried doing 89 IF statements but Excel told me that only 64 statements can be nested. I tried using VLOOKUP but I keep getting a #N/A error.

```
ZIP                                          ZIPCODES                     CountyName
45373                   45105 45144 45616 45618 45650 45660 45679 45684 45693 45697 Adams   
44022                   45801 45802 45804 45805 45807 45808 45809 45817 45820 45833 45850 45854 45887   Allen   
45319                   44805 44838 44840 44842 44848 44859 44864 44866 44874 44880 Ashland   
45168                   44003 44004 44005 44010 44030 44032 44041 44047 44048 44068 44076 44082 44084 44085 44088 44093 44099   Ashtabula   
43950                   45701 45710 45711 45716 45717 45719 45723 45732 45735 45739 45740 45761 45764 45766 45776 45777 45778 45780 45782   Athens   
45806                   45806 45819 45865 45869 45870 45871 45884 45885 45888 45895 45896   Auglaize   
43033                   43713 43718 43719 43759 43902 43905 43906 43909 43912 43916 43927 43928 43933 43934 43935 43937 43940 43942 43947 43950 43951 43967 43972 43977 43983 43985 Belmont   
45164                   45101 45115 45118 45119 45121 45130 45131 45154 45167 45168 45171   Brown   
45069                   45003 45004 45011 45012 45013 45014 45015 45018 45025 45026 45042 45043 45044 45050 45053 45055 45056 45061 45062 45063 45064 45067 45069 45071 Butler   
45157                   44607 44615 44620 44631 44639 44644 44651 44675 Carroll   
44629                   43009 43044 43047 43060 43070 43072 43078 43083 43084 45389 Champaign   
45369                   43010 45319 45323 45341 45344 45349 45368 45369 45372 45501 45502 45503 45504 45505 45506   Clark   
45158                   45102 45103 45106 45112 45120 45122 45140 45145 45147 45150 45153 45156 45157 45158 45160 45176 45245   Clermont   
45146                   45107 45113 45114 45138 45146 45148 45159 45164 45166 45169 45177   Clinton   
44840                   43920 43945 43962 43968 44408 44413 44415 44423 44427 44431 44432 44441 44445 44455 44460 44490 44492 44493 44625 44634 44665   Columbiana   
45863                   43803 43805 43811 43812 43824 43828 43836 43843 43844 43845 Coshocton   
45806                   44820 44825 44827 44833 44854 44856 44860 44881 44887   Crawford   
43009                   44017 44022 44040 44070 44101 44102 44103 44104 44105 44106 44107 44108 44109 44110 44111 44112 44113 44114 44115 44116 44117 44118 44119 44120 44121 44122 44123 44124 44125 44126 44127 44128 44129 44130 44131 44132 44133 44134 44135 44136 44137 44138 44139 44140 44141 44142 44143 44144 44145 44146 44147 44149 44178 44181 44185 44188 44189 44190 44191 44192 44193 44194 44195 44197 44198 44199 Cuyahoga   
45887                   45303 45304 45328 45331 45332 45346 45348 45350 45351 45352 45358 45362 45380 45388 45390   Darke   
45118                   43512 43519 43520 43526 43530 43536 43549 43556 Defiance   
45740                   43003 43015 43021 43032 43035 43061 43065 43066 43074 43082 43240   Delaware   
45372                   43438 44089 44814 44816 44824 44839 44846 44870 44871   Erie   
43910                   43046 43102 43105 43107 43112 43130 43136 43147 43148 43150 43154 43155 43157 43163 Fairfield   
45176                   43106 43128 43142 43160 Fayette   
43357                   43002 43004 43016 43017 43026 43054 43068 43081 43085 43086 43109 43110 43119 43123 43125 43126 43137 43195 43196 43198 43199 43201 43202 43203 43204 43205 43206 43207 43209 43210 43211 43212 43213 43214 43215 43216 43217 43218 43219 43220 43221 43222 43223 43224 43226 43227 43228 43229 43230 43231 43232 43234 43235 43236 43251 43260 43265 43266 43268 43270 43271 43272 43279 43287 43291 43299 Franklin   
44691                   43502 43515 43521 43533 43540 43553 43558 43567 Fulton   
43449                   45614 45620 45623 45631 45643 45658 45674 45685 45686   Gallia   
45373                   44021 44023 44024 44026 44033 44046 44062 44064 44065 44072 44073 44080 44086   Geauga   
43939                   45301 45305 45307 45314 45316 45324 45335 45370 45384 45385 45387 45431 45432 45433 45434 45435 Greene   
43215                   43722 43723 43725 43732 43733 43736 43749 43750 43755 43768 43772 43773 43778 43780 Guernsey   
43616                   45001 45002 45030 45033 45041 45051 45052 45111 45174 45201 45202 45203 45204 45205 45206 45207 45208 45209 45211 45212 45213 45214 45215 45216 45217 45218 45219 45220 45221 45222 45223 45224 45225 45226 45227 45228 45229 45230 45231 45232 45233 45234 45235 45236 45237 45238 45239 45240 45241 45242 45243 45244 45246 45247 45248 45249 45250 45251 45252 45253 45254 45255 45258 45262 45263 45264 45267 45268 45269 45270 45271 45273 45274 45275 45277 45280 45296 45298 45299 45999 Hamilton   
44123                   44804 45814 45816 45839 45840 45841 45858 45867 45868 45881 45889 45890 45897   Hancock   
43224                   43326 43340 43345 43346 45810 45812 45835 45836 45843 45859 Hardin   
44606                   43907 43973 43974 43976 43981 43984 43986 43988 44693 44695 44699   Harrison   
44817                   43510 43516 43523 43524 43527 43532 43534 43535 43545 43548 43550 43555 Henry   
45305                   45110 45123 45132 45133 45135 45142 45155 45172 Highland   
44646                   43111 43127 43135 43138 43144 43149 43152 43158 Hocking   
43777                   44610 44611 44617 44628 44633 44637 44638 44654 44660 44661 44687 44690 Holmes   
44047                   44811 44826 44837 44847 44850 44851 44855 44857 44865 44888 44889 44890 Huron   
44278                   45621 45640 45656 45692 Jackson   
45874                   43901 43903 43908 43910 43913 43917 43925 43926 43930 43932 43938 43939 43941 43943 43944 43948 43952 43953 43961 43963 43964 43970 43971   Jefferson   
43465                   43005 43006 43011 43014 43019 43022 43028 43037 43048 43050 Knox   
44124                   44045 44057 44060 44061 44077 44081 44092 44094 44095 44096 44097   Lake   
43469                   45619 45638 45645 45659 45669 45675 45678 45680 45688 45696 Lawrence   
44004                   43001 43008 43013 43018 43023 43025 43027 43030 43031 43033 43055 43056 43058 43062 43071 43073 43080 43093 43098 43721 43740   Licking   
45828                   43310 43311 43318 43319 43324 43331 43333 43336 43343 43347 43348 43357 43358 43360 Logan   
44471                   44001 44011 44012 44028 44035 44036 44039 44044 44049 44050 44052 44053 44054 44055 44074 44090 Lorain   
45142                   43434 43504 43528 43537 43542 43547 43560 43566 43571 43601 43603 43604 43605 43606 43607 43608 43609 43610 43611 43612 43613 43614 43615 43616 43617 43618 43620 43623 43635 43652 43656 43657 43659 43660 43661 43666 43667 43681 43682 43697 43699   Lucas   
44902                   43064 43140 43143 43151 43153 43162 Madison   
43314                   44401 44405 44406 44416 44422 44429 44436 44442 44443 44451 44452 44454 44471 44501 44502 44503 44504 44505 44506 44507 44509 44510 44511 44512 44513 44514 44515 44555 44609 44619 44672   Mahoning   
44087                   43301 43302 43306 43307 43314 43322 43332 43335 43337 43341 43342 43356 Marion   
43017                   44212 44215 44233 44235 44251 44253 44254 44256 44258 44273 44274 44275 44280 44281 44282   Medina   
45711                   45720 45741 45743 45760 45769 45770 45771 45772 45775 45779 45783   Meigs   
45371                   45310 45822 45826 45828 45846 45860 45862 45866 45882 45883 Mercer   
44212                   45308 45312 45317 45318 45326 45337 45339 45356 45359 45361 45371 45373 45374 45383 Miami   
45236                   43716 43747 43752 43754 43757 43786 43789 43793 43914 43915 43931 43946 Monroe   
44092                   45309 45315 45322 45325 45327 45342 45343 45345 45354 45377 45401 45402 45403 45404 45405 45406 45408 45409 45410 45412 45413 45414 45415 45416 45417 45418 45419 45420 45422 45423 45424 45426 45427 45428 45429 45430 45437 45439 45440 45441 45448 45449 45454 45458 45459 45463 45469 45470 45475 45479 45481 45482 45490   Montgomery   
44114                   43728 43756 43758 43787 Morgan   
45335                   43315 43317 43320 43321 43325 43334 43338 43349 43350   Morrow   
43105                   43701 43701 43702 43702 43720 43727 43734 43735 43738 43746 43762 43767 43771 43777 43791 43802 43821 43822 43830 43842 Muskingum   
45236                   43711 43717 43724 43779 43788 45727 Noble   
43723                   43408 43412 43416 43430 43432 43433 43436 43439 43440 43445 43446 43449 43452 43456 43458 43468 Ottawa   
45876                   45813 45821 45849 45851 45855 45861 45873 45879 45880   Paulding   
45338                   43076 43730 43731 43739 43748 43760 43761 43764 43766 43782 43783   Perry   
44113                   43103 43113 43116 43117 43145 43146 43156 43164 Pickaway   
44215                   45613 45624 45642 45646 45661 45683 45687 45690 Pike   
44114                   44201 44202 44211 44231 44234 44240 44241 44242 44243 44255 44260 44265 44266 44272 44285 44288 44411 44412 44449   Portage   
44012                   45070 45311 45320 45321 45330 45338 45347 45378 45381 45382 Preble   
44113                   45815 45827 45830 45831 45837 45844 45848 45853 45856 45864 45875 45876 45877 45893 Putnam   
44460                   44813 44822 44843 44862 44875 44878 44901 44902 44903 44904 44905 44906 44907 44999 Richland   
44837                   43101 43115 45601 45612 45617 45628 45633 45644 45647 45673 45681   Ross   
45429                   43407 43410 43420 43431 43435 43442 43464 43469 Sandusky   
44256                   45629 45630 45636 45648 45652 45653 45657 45662 45663 45671 45677 45682 45694 45699 Scioto   
45723                   44802 44807 44809 44815 44818 44828 44830 44836 44841 44845 44853 44861 44867 44883 Seneca   
45133                   45302 45306 45333 45334 45336 45340 45353 45360 45363 45365 45367 45845 Shelby   
44089                   44601 44608 44613 44614 44626 44630 44632 44640 44641 44643 44646 44647 44648 44650 44652 44657 44662 44666 44669 44670 44685 44688 44689 44701 44702 44703 44704 44705 44706 44707 44708 44709 44710 44711 44712 44714 44718 44720 44721 44730 44735 44750 44767 44799 Stark   
45424                   44056 44067 44087 44203 44210 44216 44221 44222 44223 44224 44232 44236 44237 44250 44262 44264 44278 44286 44301 44302 44303 44304 44305 44306 44307 44308 44309 44310 44311 44312 44313 44314 44315 44316 44317 44319 44320 44321 44322 44325 44326 44328 44333 44334 44372 44393 44396 44398 44399   Summit   
44661                   44402 44403 44404 44410 44417 44418 44420 44424 44425 44428 44430 44437 44438 44439 44440 44444 44446 44450 44453 44470 44473 44481 44482 44483 44484 44485 44486 44488 44491   Trumbull   
44122                   43804 43832 43837 43840 44612 44621 44622 44624 44629 44653 44656 44663 44671 44678 44679 44680 44681 44682 44683 44697 Tuscarawas  
43213                   43007 43029 43036 43040 43041 43045 43067 43077 43344   Union   
43125                   45832 45838 45863 45874 45886 45891 45894 45898 45899   Van Wert   
43457                   45622 45634 45651 45654 45672 45695 45698   Vinton   
44286                   45005 45032 45034 45036 45039 45040 45054 45065 45066 45068 45152 45162 Warren   
45888                   45712 45713 45714 45715 45721 45724 45729 45734 45742 45744 45745 45746 45750 45767 45768 45773 45784 45786 45787 45788 45789   Washington   
45011                   44214 44217 44230 44270 44276 44287 44606 44618 44627 44636 44645 44659 44667 44676 44677 44691 Wayne   
45014                   43501 43505 43506 43517 43518 43531 43543 43554 43557 43570 Williams   
44264                   43402 43403 43406 43413 43414 43437 43441 43443 43447 43450 43451 43457 43460 43462 43463 43465 43466 43467 43511 43522 43525 43529 43541 43551 43552 43565 43569 43619 43654 44817 45872   Wood   
45347                   43316 43323 43330 43351 43359 44844 44849 44882 Wyandot
```

This is my Vlookup

```
=VLOOKUP(I2, N2:N89, O2:O89, TRUE)
```

If the Zip is found within the ZipCodes range return the value of CountyName of the row that is found.

Comment: Try `=VLOOKUP("*" & I2 & "*", N2:O89, 2, TRUE)`

Comment: Thank you @ScottCraner the formula that did the trick was this one, it took my a while to figure it out!

`=VLOOKUP("*"&I2&"*", N2:O89, 2, 0)`

Comment: If @Lostaunaum don't you mind... please share this solution at the answer + accept(after 48 hrs) to remove this Q from SE 'unanswered' list.